# Drupal 7, open an Accordion tab through the URL

Tags: url, drupal, tabs, accordion

I have an accordion view as block in a page. It has multiple sections (tabs) and I am trying to open it via a link to a certain section.
For example, the block named "resources" has the following tabs:
Photos
Documents
Audio Files
Video Files

Is it possible by using a specific link to that page with the "resources" block opened at a specific section/tab, say the Audio Files?

Comment: Yes, it should be possible using a fragment identifier in the url (hash), and it depends on what is actually making the blocks behave like tabs. Can you share an HTML sample ? What did you try so far ?

Comment: I am using the ViewsAccordion module in Drupal 7. I have tried passing arguments to the url of the page that has that block, but it always open on the first tab.